# iPod Touch can't download apps

Tags: ipod-touch, ios-appstore

Since yesterday, my first-generation iPod Touch would not let me download apps. In the app store, the image description (the one that you can slide left and right) would not appear and was replaced by small rectangles. The [free] or [0.99] button does not respond.

My iPod Touch is not jailbroken, and is updated with the latest firmware (3.1).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you run out of storage space? oh and it's called an iPod Touch, not an iTouch

Comment: no, I still have over a GB left

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar problems in the past and it tends to be fixed by force quitting the app, by double tapping the home button so the multi-tasking tray appears, holding down the app until the red 'x' appears and then tapping that before opening the app store again.

Comment: iOS3.1 does not have the multitasking switcher. This seems to be a universal issue on iOS3, Apple probably changed something in the app store that broke compatibility. The best thing you can do is contact apple to help bring up the issue and hopefully apple will fix it (they will probably tell you to get a new device).

Comment: My iPod Touch does not support multitasking

Comment: Sorry David, on iOS 3.1 you can achieve the same thing by holding down the power button then sliding to power off before powering on again.